# SharedPreference in Android making problems. "String lastAlertTime = lastAlertTimeSettings.getString(LAST_ALERT_TIME, null)" returning null

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPreference in my Android app to store a string value, but it always takes the defValue from .getString(String key, String defValue), despite having a set value.

Here is my code:

```
public class AddAlert extends Activity {

[...]

public static final String LAST_ALERT_TIME = "1414931472952";

[...]

public boolean checkIfMoreThanTenMinutesFromLastAlert() {

        SharedPreferences lastAlertTimeSettings = getSharedPreferences(LAST_ALERT_TIME, 0);
        String lastAlertTime = lastAlertTimeSettings.getString(LAST_ALERT_TIME, null);
        double currentDate = new Date().getTime();

        if (getDifference(currentDate, Double.valueOf(lastAlertTime))/1000/60>10) {

            return true;

        } else return false;
    }

    public double getDifference(double currentDate, double lastAlertDate) {

        //milliseconds
        double difference = currentDate - lastAlertDate;

        return difference;
    }
}
```

The problem is that LAST_ALERT_TIME has a preset value, but it always returns the defValue("null" in this case").

Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Thank you!

Comment: why are you using LAST_ALERT_TIME as the key? That's weird. Anyways, what you need to do, is first store something (like default value) against the key LAST_ALERT_TIME and then when you retrieve the value, you won't get null.

Answer (score 0):

before you GET a preference in your app,

1. make sure you set the source of data
2. provide a real value for your key that you are getting

   ```
   PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.default_values, false);  


          SharedPreferences.Editor ed = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
          ed.putString("LAST_ALERT_TIME", getString(R.string.db_app_id));
          ed.apply(); // or commit()
   ```